# Cache de página não está expirando

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cache, static

Eu estou usando o caches_page em um controller na minha aplicação em rails 4.

```
caches_page :index, expires_in: 10.minutes
```

Eu preciso fazer com que esse controller rode novamente após 10 minutos e gere uma nova página. Quando eu rodo isso no ambiente de produção depois de 10 minutos a página não é expirada.

Estou usando o :memory_store no meu config

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

Como eu posso resolver isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri qual é o problema.
O expires_in só funciona se você estiver utilizando o Memcached ou algo similar (como Redis, por exemplo).

Mesmo assim só funciona no caches_action. O caches_page é feito para páginas que não serão alteradas nunca ou rodar manualmente no controller o expires_page('/rota').

Fonte: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionController/Caching/Actions

Comment: Você pode marcar sua resposta como correta para "encerrar" a questão.